# How to remove padding on the last element of a list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need help with code. I need to implement a list of buttons. Make a distance of 24 pixels between each button. Below I have attached screenshots of what I have at the moment and what I need to get in the end result. So, in order to set the spacing between elements I use `Padding` `right`. But because of this, I also have an indent in the last element on the right. I need to remove it. The second problem with the text, you can see that there is very small text under one element, how can I make the text of a normal size but at the same time so that the distance between the elements does not change, otherwise if I set the normal text size now in that place, I have a distance from for the text will be different?

**code**

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: connectors.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 47,
                            height: 47,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: constants.Colors.greyDark, width: 0.5),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              connectors.keys.elementAt(index),
                              color: constants.Colors.greyConnector,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 4),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 47,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Text(
                                connectors.values.elementAt(index),
                                style: constants
                                    .Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite
                                    .copyWith(
                                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

**This is what I have now**

[image]

**I need this at the end**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: index == connectors.length - 1 ? 0 : 24),
```

Comment: Another question, how can I solve the problem with the text so that it is not so small? It's just that if you do not place it in a FittedBox, then because of the text, the distance between the elements will not be 24 pixels, but more.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do about the Padding to the right is: Instead of giving a padding to each of the items in the `ListView`, put your:

```
Column(
    children: [
        Container(
            width: 47,
            height: 47,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                border: Border.all(
                color: constants.Colors.greyDark, width: 0.5),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                connectors.keys.elementAt(index),
                color: constants.Colors.greyConnector,
            ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 4),
        SizedBox(
            width: 47,
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                child: Text(
                    connectors.values.elementAt(index),
                    style: constants
                        .Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite
                        .copyWith(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Inside a `Row` and check, if it is not the last item of your list, then add a `SizedBox` with width: 24, if it's indeed the last item just add a `Container` like this:

```
Row(children: [
    yourWidget(),
    index != connectors.length - 1 ? SizedBox(width: 24) : Container()
])
```

About the second question:

I would suggest that you use `Expanded` or `Flexible` Widget for the texts, it would break the role if your text reached the max width of the first one, otherwise I can't see how it can't be done unless you give a custom size depending on the index of the item you are passing to the `ListView`, for example:

```
SizedBox(
    width: isIndexOfChaDeMo ? customWidth : 47,
    child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text(
            connectors.values.elementAt(index),
            style: constants
                .Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite
                .copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
        )
    )
)
```

You would also need to customize the "padding" you are passing to the item to the right and left of this one, and all of this would change in case you needed to translate your app in the future for example, that's why I suggest you Use Expanded or Flexible(take a look at these widgets on the documentation) as parents of the text so it can go to the next line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
Another question, how can I solve the problem with the text so that it is not so small? It's just that if you do not place it in a FittedBox, then because of the text, the distance between the elements will not be 24 pixels, but more.